# Can you invite Guest user in Azure Government cloud AAD tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-gov

I am trying to invite a guest user in Azure USA Government Cloud AAD tenant.

But I received error that says:

> The user you are inviting does not exist in this national cloud. To collaborate with this user, ask them for a different email address associated with the directory in this national cloud or create User Account for them in your AAD

**How do I fix this problem?** I do not have an option to create a guest account as per the org policy. So I can only invite a guest user.

I never had this problem while inviting guest users in Azure commercial cloud.

Does it mean that you do not have any option to invite guest users from consulting companies with an email address that is not in the US Gov cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that you do not have any option to invite guest users
> from consulting companies with an email address that is not in the US
> Gov cloud?

Within the Azure US Government cloud, B2B collaboration is currently only supported between tenants that are both within Azure US Government cloud and that both support B2B collaboration. If you invite a user in a tenant that isn't part of the Azure US Government cloud or that doesn't yet support B2B collaboration, you'll get an error.

> How do I fix this problem?

Ask the user for another email address or create a member user account for the user in your Azure AD directory

please see: [Limitations of Azure AD B2B collaboration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/current-limitations).